# How to migrate from MySql to HSQLDB?

Tags: java, mysql

I have large amount of data in a MySQL database.

There are many databases schemas in the database.

How I can migrate from MySQL to HSQLDB?

Is there some tool for this?

I've exported the data manually.  How can I export only schema.sql?

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to do this. I has never heard of hsqldb before this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Comparison of database tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools), there you find some tools supporting both `HSQL`
 and `MySQL`. Then it should be possible to export the MySQL DB and directly import to HSQL DB from the same GUI.

Answer (score 1):

PhpMyAdmin (Requires a Web Server with PHP) is a tool that is able to create SQL Scripts for Schema and Data. -- The good thing is, it creates SQL scripts, so you can insert the Schema and data to the most other SQL Databases.

So if you have it already installe then you can use it. If you do not have it installed jet, then I would search for an other tool.

Comment: Phpmyadmin is incredibly heavy weight just to get a schema dump!

Comment: Aaron Brown: That is exacly why I have written: "So if you have it already installe then you can use it. If you do not have it installed jet, then I would search for an other tool."

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump -d --all-databases -u root -p > schema.sql` will dump your schema without data.  Use `man mysqldump` and `mysqldump -h` to see what other options are available.

two questions, though...

1. Why?
2. What do you consider "very big? "

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is at least one tool. It's not free, but there is a free trial :
http://razorsql.com/features/hsqldb_database_conversion.html